# Firefox Quantum: Event pane does not appear on Developer tab in Developer Edition

Tags: firefox, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

Firefox Quantum: Developer Edition 68.0b14 (64-bit) is used.

Here, I wanted to use this browser to monitor text changes that occur in the DOM. Since changes to that DOM are triggered by event handlers not tied to that DOM, I need to monitor changes to the DOM directly.

So I thought the [event pane](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Break_on_a_DOM_event) was useful.

---

However, this feature is not yet supported by the new debugger. The event pane did not appear when you set `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend` to`false`.

Can I use this feature instead? To monitor changes in elements.

Google chrome has an item "Break on" when right-clicking an element, but Firefox does not. Do you have equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I [asked about this on MDN's GitHub](https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/1773) and the answer is:

> Starting in Firefox 69, the Debugger will include the ability to select an event and automatically add a breakpoint that will fire when the handler for that event is hit. If you want to play with it, you can download Firefox Developer edition.

Weirdly it doesn't list the specific handlers you can select from, only the event types.

And it won't be useful if the page itself doesn't have the handler for the specified mutation.

Here's how it looks:

[image: "Event Listener Breakpoints" in the "Debugger" pane]